# Add Web Reference with certificates on https

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0

I was adding a web service via "Add Web Reference" to my project. The web service was only accessible on https with a client certificate.When I did "Add Web Reference" I got a "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send". I found an other way to add the web service via "Add Web Reference" but i don't know how to use this way ??

1-Save the WSDL to a location on your machine.

2-Copy the path.

3-Go to the Add Web Reference in your project.

4-Paste the path you copied into the URL.

6-Click on Add Reference

(my project build using visual studio 2015 and c# 4)

should i change all of addresses in the wsdl file to https ?